# CSRF token undefined in client-side while using lusca

Tags: node.js, vue.js, csrf, csrf-protection, express-session

I'm using [lusca](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lusca) and express-session in the Node layer of a VueJS application and am trying to prevent CSRF attacks. I'm using the following lusca configuration:

```
import lusca from "lusca";
import config from "../../properties/config.js";

export default function (app) {

    const luscaConfig = {
       csrf: true,
       xssProtection: config.get("security:xss:enabled")
    };

    if (config.get("security:csp:enabled")) {
        luscaConfig.csp = {
            policy: config.get("security:csp:policy")
        };
    }

    if (config.get("security:xframe:enabled")) {
        luscaConfig.xframe = config.get("security:xframe:origin");
    } 

    if (config.get("security:p3p:enabled")) {
        luscaConfig.p3p = config.get("security:p3p:policy");
    }

    app.use(lusca(luscaConfig));
};
```

With just this, I'm able to see the following error on the first action I take in the web client that interacts with the API (signing in):

[image]

Cool, so it looks like to a certain extent the lusca configuration is doing its job, now I just need to do the right thing in the client-side to make sure the CSRF token is set in the headers of outgoing requests properly. I saw that [this post](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-can-i-use-csrf-token-with-axios-post-method) looked helpful to my cause, especially the answer provided by user abusalameh. In the main.js file of my Vue app where I'm instantiating the app itself, I added the following:

```
import axios from 'axios'

window.axios = axios
console.log(document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]'))
```

However, `null` is being logged out and it appears the CSRF token is not being detected. How can I access the CSRF token being supplied by lusca to then be able to set it in the headers and ensure my requests are properly recognized but not those of malicious agents?

Comment: _If enabled, the CSRF token must be in the payload when modifying data or you will receive a 403 Forbidden. **To send the token you'll need to echo back the `_csrf` value you received from the previous request.**_

Comment: Furthermore, you didn't show how you echo CSRF token into your initial HTML.